# Putting a form between 2 divs

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am currently learning css and bootstrap and I am currently trying to recreate a very simple layout but I am having a few problems.

Basically I have 2 divs on top of each other and I want to have a form that will span in the 2 divs. ANd I am not quite sure how to achieve that.

HTML :

```
<div class="one">
<div class="container">
<div class="row mx-auto">
<div class="col-sm">
  One of three columns
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
  One of three columns
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
  One of three columns
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="two">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm">
  One of three columns
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
  One of three columns
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
  One of three columns
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form">
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" 
 placeholder="name@example.com">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
<select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
<textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"> 
</textarea>
</div>
</form></div>
```

CSS :

```
.one {
height: 50vh;
background-color : black;
color : white;
}

.two {
height: 50vh;
background-color : red;
color : white;
}

.form {
width: 30%;
}
```

this is some basic example I put together in Codepen :

https://codepen.io/JeremyLemer1/pen/MWgKXzL

Here is a basic image of how i want it to look like :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr9dg.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```css
.bigdiv {
  height: 300px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
.smalldiv {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  background: orange;
  float: right;
  margin-right:10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /*
  you can use margin-top:-50px; for browser compatibility
  margin top shoult be -(half of div height);
  
  */
}

.bigdiv1 {
  height: 300px;
  background: darkblue;
  border: 6px solid black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='bigdiv'>
      <p> Random Text</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class='smalldiv'>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" 
             placeholder="name@example.com">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
            <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
             </select>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"> 
            </textarea>
            </div>
            </form>
    </div>
    <div class='bigdiv1'>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In, vel iusto. Rem, quidem necessitatibus. Earum odit consequuntur veniam sapiente. Debitis possimus distinctio minus culpa velit corporis, repellendus nihil perferendis cum quam illum dignissimos in nulla atque odit pariatur, eaque praesentium reprehenderit molestias adipisci quibusdam dolorum perspiciatis quos dicta? Recusandae, voluptas dolorem pariatur autem maiores dicta accusamus quis dolorum, alias, voluptatem tempora beatae saepe o  </p>
    </div>
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What About making it possible through css? Position absolute can do this work.

```
.form {
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 5%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: I know I can do it with absolute positioning. But is there another way?

Comment: @Pete You have to create a parent div and give it a gradient color for form to make it blend in with a theme,  a little HTML customization with container and rows. I have done this on this snippet. https://codepen.io/alimughal01/pen/PoYZBze

Comment: other than it is not possible to put it in 2 divs, it is not possible. or you can break the form into 2 divs, half for one div and other half for second div

Answer (score 0):

CSS grid is good at solving these types of problems. A quick and dirty solution for you would be this code I changed from your Codepen:

```
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 50vh;
}

.two {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color : red;
  color : white;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

Instead of using `body` though, I would create a parent div. Grid works with a parent/child relationship.

```css
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 50vh;
}

.one {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color : black;
  color : white;
  
}

.two {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color : red;
  color : white;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.form {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
  
 <div class="parent">
 <div class="one">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="two">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form">
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
</form></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the form to be inside the  2 divs. In the red and black ones.